# Auth Token for Azure Web API

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I'm having issues with using tokens to access my Azure Web API. I followed [this documentation from Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad/#configure-a-desktop-application-to-call-the-api).

I can successfully request an access token by doing a POST request to the authorization token endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant ID}/oauth2/token
```

My POST body:

```
client_id:( Web API client ID )
client_secret:( Web API client Secret )
grant_type:password
username:userName
password:*******
resource:sharepoint.com
```

I'm using POSTMAN to test my calls and when I try to access my API using that returned token from above, I get a `401` unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Was a configuration issue inside my WebConfig file.